# I need help finding coefficients of polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have the polynomial  $p(z)=az^{2}+bz+c$ .

I also have the roots:

$z_0=-6$

$z_1=6-i$

And I also know that:

$p(-i)=-6$

Given this information I have to find the coefficients $a,b, c$.

I know that a polynomial with roots $z_0$ and $z_1$ will have the factors $(z-z_0)(z-z_1)$ so what I've tried is:

[image]

But this approach does not take into consideration that $p(-i)=-6$ and is therefore the wrong solution.

Comment: Try with factor in front, $k(z-z_1)(z-z_2).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine; you've forgotten two things.

1. It has those as factors, but could have OTHER factors as well
2. The other factors can only be a constant, because you know it's a quadratic and has only two roots. So you just need to say

$$
A(z-z_0)(z-z_1) = A(z+6)(z-6+i) = \ldots
$$

and then you need to use your final constraint to determine the value of $A$.

Comment: Or even better, plug in $z=-i$ immediately.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to pursue OP's approach to the degree possible, and at the same time correct a small misconception. Frankly, if I were doing it myself, I'd plug in all three known things and write a system of 3 eqns in the 3 unknown coefficients and then solve it...

Comment: so I set $p(-i)=-6$ and then isolate for A :)?

Comment: Looks as if you figured that out, but the answer is "yes". :)